# How can I run a selenium webdriver as a background process in Python?

Tags: python, selenium

How would this work? I got no idea I'm kinda new to selenium lol.

Comment: headless = True?

Comment: not sure maybe i can test it?

Comment: nope that doesnt work

Answer (score 2):

If you are using chrome driver you can do that by adding headless to the browser options like so:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

options.add_argument('--headless')


with webdriver.Chrome(options=options) as browser:

       browser.get(url)
       # # Do other stuff
```

or

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

options.add_argument('--headless')

browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options) 

browser.get(url)

# # do things

browser.close()
```

Comment: that also doesnt work, its weird

Comment: @2x0Z I have the exact same code and it's working, you must be doing something wrong, make sure that you are passing the options keyword to chrome driver, I have included that in the answer check it and let me know if it's worked

Comment: with does not exist apparently lol

Comment: what do you mean by not exist?
`with` works like a resource manager in this case it will close the browser automatically when the code inside it is executed, you don't have to use `with`  but it's recommended to use it.

you can use it like this:

browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options) 
browser.get(url)
# # do things

browser.close()

Comment: Works with Firefox, too. In that case use `webdriver.FirefoxOptions()`

Comment: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home